# compile all cpp files in directory with makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I am doing a project which is growing pretty fast and manually compiles the project is getting to much work. Therefore i want a makefile to automize this process. I makefile should only compile all the files from the src directory (and all those files in subfolders).

Project directory is as follows:

```
-src
--files.cpp
--files.h
--|-dirA
---|-aa.cpp
---|-aa.h
---|-ab.cpp
---|-ab.h
--|-dirB
---|-ba.cpp
---|-ba.h
---|-bb.cpp
---|-bb.h
```

and a main.cpp in the root directory

So far my makefile gets all the cpp files from the src folder:

```
SRC_DIR ?= ./src
OBJ_DIR := ./obj
SRC_FILES := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -name '*.cpp')
```

I'm not sure how to continue from this.

Comment: Using a build system like [CMake](https://cmake.org/) or [SCons](https://scons.org/) *may* be a better option in the long run.

Comment: You don't really need to do much thanks to [*implicit rules*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html) and wildcards: `obj/%.o: src/%.cpp`

Comment: `SRC_DIRS` has an `S` in your `SRC_FILES` definition.   You would likely want to define `OBJ_FILES := $(SRC_FILES:$(SRC_DIR)%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)`, and then make a target for your main program `program: $(OBJ_FILES)` with a recipe to link the object files.  Finally create a pattern rule to generate the .o files from the .cpp files with the right directories: `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o:$(SRC_DIR)/%.c` ...